# Migrating OpenID2 to OpenID Connect or Google+ Sign-in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, google-plus, google-openid, openid-connect

My ASP.NET MVC 4 application uses OpenID2 authentication that went with MVC templates (out of the box) and only uses Google accounts for authentication, no other social features are integrated.

Now I need to migrate OpenID2 because it will be shutdown in April: 
[Migration OpenID2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)

It seems that I could use one of two options to do this migration:

- OpenID Connect
- Google+ Sign-in

I would like to understand better which differences between the two methods and the advantages/disadvantages of one related to the other.

Until now, I think that the biggest difference is that OpenID Connect is used essencially to authentication and Google+ Sign-in has authentication and social features. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google+ Sign-In provides OAuth 2.0 (OpenID Connect) authentication with rich social features and access to additional Google desktop and mobile features.

Right from the link you have you can see that Google+ Sign-In is OpenID connect. Using Google+ Sign-In however adds some social features and some usability improvements for getting integrated into your site.